# Firestore DB design to exclude a document after N reads / day

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

I am trying to make a dating app, somewhat similar to Tinder, using Firebase Firestore.
There is one interesting DB design problem that I want to solve optimally.

**About**

Each day, my profile will be shown to a limited number of people (say 100 people) who logged in that day. For now let's forget about the distance and other matching factors, and just consider showing my profile to 100 new random people each day.

**Problem**

What kind of Firestore DB design would be needed to implement this ?
I do have one idea how to solve this (see below), but it has many cons.
Can you suggest a better idea ?

**My Solution so far** :

I maintain a firestore collection, where each profile is one document in it. And each profile document maintains a `todaysReadCount` field that keeps track of how many times the profile has been read today.

Then use this query to fetch 50 profile for each user :

```
firestore.collection("Profiles").where('todaysReadCount','<=', 100).limit(50).get();
```

As soon as the fetch is complete, the client (app) will right away update all these 50 profile documents with `todaysReadCount + 1`

```
foreach uid_i in fetched50profiles {
  firestore.collection("Profiles").doc(uid_i).update({
    todaysReadCount: FieldValue.increment(1)
  });
}
```

Every mid-night a cloud function resets this counter in all the profiles.

Theoretically this should work, but there are multiple problems with this approach:

1. There will be many writes just to maintain the counter. Atleast 100 writes / profile / day. This will increase my firestore bill $$$.
2. Updating all profile docs at midnight, is also a huge overhead, and will cost $$$.
3. Since reading the profile and updating their counter is not a single transaction, there will be a delay between reading & updating. This may result in more profile reads than 100, if huge number of people log in simultaneously. (But this is not a big problem irl I guess)

Can you suggest a better solution ?

Comment: You'll have to maintain that `todaysReadCount` field for this case. Can you provide more details on where are you running this logic? I see a Cloud function is being used only for periodic resets. I generally use [Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) for such use cases where I can locally cache the UIDs and those counts and then update those periodically update them to Firestore. So instead of updating document for every view, accumulate count of views for example 5 minutes and update them in Firestore.

Comment: @Dharmaraj, These queries and update calls will run at client (phone apps). I doubt I can use any caching, since the clients will be talking directly to the Firestore. Using a compute in between is not a serverless arch that Firestore is meant for. ( and I plan to stay serverless )

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to answer because there are a lot of design decisions involved along with a lot of variables and unknowns. SO is a coding specific site; write some code and when you get stuck, post it and we'll take a look.This question is asking for a solution without us knowing the scope of the project. For example; what if a user logs in, is shown your profile and logs out. Then logs back in again. Do they see your profile again? How to prevent that? You mention cost of 100 writes/profile. What if there are 100,000 profiles? That cost needs to be built into the pricing.

Comment: Hi @Jay , I know the entire DB design for the app is difficult and that is why I asked one specific question, pin pointed to my need with the relevant query & code sample. Now to answer your question, if user logs in once (fetches all 50 profiles) and logs out without seeing most of the profiles, all the fetched profiles are stored locally for that day. So the app wont fetch again. As for cost of 100,000 profiles, I have solution for that too. But what i need is the answer to this specific question, and Frank was able to answer it to some extent.

Comment: *So the app wont fetch again* - how do you prevent that? The question asks how to exclude data; if the app fetches 50 profiles and stores them locally for that day, when they log back in 2 hours later, how do you prevent the app from reading those 50 profiles again and incrementing the counters? There's nothing wrong with the question, but if you want to exclude data to reduce the reads/writes, we would need to understand how that's handled. While @frankvanpuffelen answer is helpful, it won't prevent the app re-reading the same profile over and over, nor present the data to 100 random people.

Comment: @Jay, _not fetching data again_ is pretty simple actually. `if (localStorage.todaysDateProfiles == null) { localStorage.todaysDateProfiles = db.collection('profile').where(...).limit(50).get(); } // use localStorage.todaysDateProfiles to display profiles`. And I know this works bcoz i am doing this with one of my apps that's already in production.

Comment: I see, so you're saying that if there are *any* profiles stored locally, it doesn't read firebase at all. Gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to reduce the need for *nightly* clean up would be to store the counters per date, and not just for today. So add a field for each day:

```
readCount_20200413: 100,
readCount_20200414: 42,
readCount_20200415: 1
```

While you'll still need to clean these counters up periodically to prevent running over the maximum document size or number of indexes, you can do it at a much lower interval and thus reduce the number of nightly writes.

You will need to pre-seed the count for upcoming dates to 0 with this, as queries will otherwise not return the document if no count is present for a date.

---

Another improvement would be to store the counters in a system that meets your billing requirements better, and what Dharmaraj commented as a cache. For example, you can keep the counters in the Firebase Realtime Database, which will typically be much cheaper for this use-case.

You can then either query against this alternate data source, or you can check on every write whether the new counter value exceeds your threshold and update the profile in Firestore when it does to exclude it from queries there.

So you'd end up with the counters in Realtime Database, and simpler boolean fields in Firestore, which also means you won't need a range query there.

```
canShowOn_20200413: false,
canShowOn_20200414: true,
canShowOn_20200415: true
canShowOn_20200416: true
canShowOn_20200417: true
```

Comment: Storing the counters per date is interesting. So the daily reset function could now be a weekly or even monthly reset function (to delete past dates) that also seeds dates for next one. _Savings++_

Comment: @Frank, Thanks for suggesting the innovative ways to reduce cost. Using RTDB for counters is excellent.

Comment: @Frank I tried your solution, it was working perfectly on emulator, but as soon as I tried it on real firestore, it is asking me to create a composite index including `canShowOn_20220903` bool field (along with other fields like `gender` etc in the query). This Date will change tomorrow, and I cant create a new composite index each day.
I am back to square one. :(